# Commons getting uploaded file content to a string value

Tags: java, apache-commons

Through `apache commons` I am uploading a file, I want to read all its content to a String and pass them to my JSP page through a `RequestDispatcher`.

How do I read the contents of the uploading file in String format?

Comment: Do you have the absolute path of the file? If yes, why don't you were able to search for "read file java"?

Comment: You most likely read the file as you would any other file, via a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
FileUtils.readFileToString(File file)
```

from the commons-io package